# Cycling through angular objects onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image]I'm trying to use jquery to hide the opacity of the first 3 products by clicking the left arrow and then I want the next 3 products to fade into view. I can get the first 3 to fade out without moving the arrows by hiding opacity. So when they are invisible the products will change and then I will fade into view the next 3 products.
I can't seem to figure out how to change out the first 3 images on click with the next 3 images. Can anyone help me with this?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='formApp'>

<head>
    <title>Bicycle App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class='row'>

                <div class='col-md-12'>

                    <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"><span>&nbsp;{{"Bike Shop"}}</span></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                <!-- end class not needed -->
                <div class="chooseTitle">
                    Choose Your Bicycle
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                <!-- you missed md from offset, end class not needed -->
                <div class="products" ng-controller="BikeController">
                  <div class="row">


     <div class="col-md-1" id="leftArrow"><a ng-href="#"><img ng-src="images/leftarrow.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
<div class="bikesandtitles">
                  <div id="bikeTitle" class="col-md-3 text-center" ng-repeat="product in products | limitTo:-3">
                  {{product.manufacturer}}
                  <img id="bikePic" ng-src="{{product.image}}">
                  </div>
                       </div>
                   <div class="col-md-1" id="rightArrow"><a ng-href="#"><img ng-src="images/rightarrow.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>



</div>
                </div><!--End controller-->




    </div>



    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bikeimageslider.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

bikeimageslider.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#leftArrow').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

   $('.bikesandtitles').fadeTo(800, 0);
});
});
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('formApp', []);
app.controller('BikeController',['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.products = [
{
manufacturer: "Trek",
image: 'images/bike1.jpg'
}, 
{
manufacturer: "Mongoose",
image: 'images/bike2.jpg'

},
{   

    manufacturer: "Portlandia",
image: 'images/bike3.jpg'
},
{

    manufacturer: "Giant",
image: 'images/bike4.jpg'
},
{

    manufacturer: "Framed",
image: 'images/bike5.jpg'
},
{
manufacturer: "Windsor",
image: 'images/bike6.jpg'
}
];


this.form = {};
this.addForm = function(product){

};

}]);
```

Comment: It is very bad idea to use jquery to manipulate the DOM while using angular. Check ngAnimate.

Comment: Ok I didn't know. I'm still new with angular. Thanks for the tip. If I were to write a function that does ng-click="myFunction() then how would I cycle through the products array when the button is clicked?

Comment: Check this: http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation